# Make a variable inherit the methods of an existing prototype?

Tags: javascript, variables, inheritance, methods

So let's say i have a tile on a map.

```
function TileData (image, z) {
    this.image = image;
    this.z = z;
}
var tile = new TileData (tileimage, 0);
```

Now i can call tile.image and tile.z to reference the existing data.

I also have an array called map, which i can loop through to draw the map.

```
var map = [];
```

What i want to do is attach the methods of the existing tile to the 0th entry in the array so it will be drawn when the function is called.

So i tried doing something like this.

```
map[0] = tile;
```

So i can call map[0].image to get the image that represents that tile on the map.

Now i want to change the image of this tile, so i try doing this.

```
map[0].image = differentTileImage;
```

However what Javascript actually does is this:

```
tile.image = differentTileImage;
```

Which means any time i try to use that tile for another part of the map, it will have a different value.

```
map[1] = tile;
//map[1].image will return differentTileImage instead of tileimage.
```

Is there a way for a variable to inherit the properties and values of an existing prototype, rather than merely referencing it?

(Sorry if this is a dupe).

Comment: The trivial solution here seems to be `map[0] = new TileData(differentTileImage, map[0].z)`, though I could see that becoming more difficult as your `TileData` constructor grows in complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use `Object.assign()`, that function will create a copy of the Tile.

```
map[1] = Object.assign({}, tile);
```

You can find more useful information at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that objects in JavaScript are always passed by reference. When you change the original, changes all values in the chain, where you use this reference.

In your case `tile` and `map[0]` are the same think. If you change tile `map[0]` is changed because the reference in the memory is the same as `tile`.

Answer (score 0):

> Which means any time i try to use that tile for another part of the map, it will have a different value.

Well not exactly. It means that when you use a single tile for every part of the map, it will have the exactly same value everywhere. And if you change this single tile, the whole map will change.

What you want is to create multiple tile instances:

```
map[0] = new TileData (tileimage, 0);
map[1] = new TileData (tileimage, 0);
…
```

(you'd use a loop of course)

They still will all inherit from the same prototype object (`TileData.prototype`), but are distinct instances and every image can be changed separately.